# What does it mean to "conditionalize a probability distrubition"?

Tags: logic, probability

What does it mean to "conditionalize a probability distrubition"?  In case relevant, I've been reading about "Adam's Thesis", and that's where this phrase has been thrown about.

Answer (score 1):

If [this definition](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095350157) is sufficent, then it is referring to the "conditional probability distribution".   Suppose that you have two random variables, described by a probability distribution p(x,y).  One can ask the question, "what is the probability distribution for x if I only considered those cases where y takes on a specific value, i.e. y=Y?".

Thinking about it in terms of a finite sample might be useful.  Suppose that you had a long list of pairs X_i, Y_i, were drawn from the joint probability distribution p(x,y).  Out of this long list of numbers, only keep those entries match your selected (conditioning) value for y, i.e. those pairs (X_i, Y_i) where Y_i==Y.  The distribution for the x values in this restricted subset is the conditional probability p(x|Y).  (Formally you get the exact probability as you let the size of your table of pairs go to infinity).

More often you'll see equations like p(x|Y)=p(x,Y)/p(Y) which embody the same idea, without the rigmarole of thinking about populations.

Answer (score 0):

Non-technically:

A probability distribution is an assignment of probabilities to each of a set of outcomes. So for rolling one fair six-sided die, we can describe six possible outcomes, each with one face up, and a flat probability distribution. It's flat because since each face has an equal chance of turning up, the bar chart of probable outcomes is the same height for each.

To conditionalize something is to express what it's like when you make it depend on (or conditional on) something else. Think of it as preceding the description with "IF some condition holds, then ... "

So for the six-sided die if you conditionalize it having already rolled a 4, you're expressing the probability of all the various rolls given that you've previously rolled a 4. For this die roll, this conditionalized probability distribution is the same.  It isn't affected by what you've rolled before.

If, however, you ask What's the probability distribution if you've glued a weight to one of the faces, well, that's going to look different!

Answer (score 0):

An example: You ask lots of people "How many children do you have?" and you will get certain answers. If you asked people at random, you would get answers "no children", "one child", "two children" etc. with certain probabilities.

Now imagine you asked people first "do you have a daughter", and they answer "Yes" or "No". Someone who answers "Yes" to the first question will certainly not answer "No children" to the second question (unless they are very confused, or misunderstood one of the questions, or they are lying). So for people answering "Yes" to the first question, the distribution of answers to the second question will be different. If you determine the distribution of answers to the second question under the condition that the answer to the first question was "Yes", that's could "conditionalizing the probabiltiy distribution".

More extreme, ask married people whether they are married to a man or a woman. About 50% for each possible answer. Now ask married men, and more than 99% will say they are married to a woman.